# Scan GS1-128 with Zxing

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner, gs1-128

I want to scan GS1-128 barcode (like picture attached) with Zxing (Android), but I can't. I'm using scanning by IntentIntegrator. Could anyone help me?

Else another barcode scanner framework for Android/iOS?

Thanks, best regards

GS1-128 barcode image: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-YK3JO8XNT30/TyZHBkkwMtI/AAAAAAAAKOg/pzrOTpeTILs/w778-h112-k/barcode.gif

Answer (score 2):

I believe I answered this in a private e-mail, but repeating here.

Your barcode is quite long, so difficult to scan, but it is possible. The format is Code 128. You need to make sure you set "SCAN_FORMATS" to "CODE_128" to enable Code 128 scanning (and disable others).

You may also have better luck widening the scanning rectangle by supplying a larger value for "SCAN_WIDTH".

Comment: The secret is larger value for SCAN_WIDTH and shorter value for SCAN_HEIGHT.

Thanks Sean.